# jconsole doesn't show classes loaded

Tags: java, jboss, jconsole

I am using Jboss 5.1, and have the below JAVA_OPTS in my run.conf -

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8080"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.platform.mbeanserver"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djavax.management.builder.initial=org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerBuilderImpl"
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=172.28.88.139"
```

I have attached my Jboss instance to my jconsole, but I don't see the classes that are getting loaded on my stdout although I have verbose output box checked. What might I be missing?